# Migrating Repositories from GitHub EE to GitLab EE Without Direct Access

Tags: github, gitlab, migration

I have several GitHub Enterprise Edition repositories that are only accessible via a VPN. I've obtained dumps of these repositories using the GHE-Migrator tool. Now, I need to import this data into GitLab Enterprise Edition, which is accessible through a different VPN.

Most solutions I've found suggest using GitLab's import feature. However, my GitLab instance cannot access GitHub's API, making this approach unavailable. Is there a way to utilize the GHE-Migrator's dump directly for this migration?

Worst case would be to migrate only the git-related data (such as commit history, branches, and tags), which I'm capable of doing. But I would like to transfer all the repository data if possible. Any suggestions?

I've tried to migrate with the .git folder and successfully got its content.  However, I don't know how to make use of the rest of the files